# callbacks are not working in while subscribing pubnub nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, pubnub

```
var PubNub = require("pubnub"); 
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    channel: 'Channel-xxxxxxxx',
    publishKey   : "pub-c-b91315c1-e6a1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    subscribeKey : "sub-c-b4735f6a-b6f6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }); 

pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: 'Channel-xxxxxxxx',
    callback: function(message) {
        console.log("Message received: ", message);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } });
```

using sample code given on pubnub documentaion still not able to make it work, don't know where i am going wrong

Comment: well got the problem with my code . i think in new version of pubnub they have changed the "channel" keyword with "channels", as it solved the problem i aws facing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var PubNub = require("pubnub"); 
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    channel: 'Channel-xxxxxxxx',
    publishKey   : "pub-c-b91315c1-e6a1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    subscribeKey : "sub-c-b4735f6a-b6f6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }); 

pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: 'Channel-xxxxxxxx',
    callback: function(message) {
        console.log("Message received: ", message);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    connect: publish
 });
```

Comment: well got the problem with my code . i think in new version of pubnub they have changed the "channel" keyword with "channels", as it solved the problem i aws facing

Comment: If you are using PubNub SDK v4, then the subscribe does not have a callback. See the [PubNub JavaScript SDK v4 docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4) on `addListener` for receiving messages, presence and status events.